# What would be the best glue to use for papermaking frames that are immersed in water & made from pinewood

Tags: glue, softwood

My son is making mould & deckle papermaking frames for me using pinewood. The frames are continually immersed in water. Could you please suggest the best glue to use for this job?

Answer (score 2):

Your best option would be a two part marine epoxy. Many of the major adhesive manufacturers produce them and hardware stores stock them so it will be easy to acquire.

Answer (score 2):

As with most things there's no one best option. There are three good choices that aren't too difficult to obtain and should be absolutely reliable:

- Epoxy
- Polyurethane
- Urea-formaldehyde

These are in no particular order. The epoxy does not need to be marine-grade.

**Additional point**
As well as going with a waterproof glue for this sort of application it would be best to use corner joints that have some structural strength, so that you aren't only relying on the glue bond.

So in essence use anything but plain mitres. These are inherently not 
strong structural joints because two end-grain surfaces are being bonded together and this is the weakest of all glue situations. If going with mitres some further reinforcement should be considered mandatory.

Preferable joints would be one of the following:

- Mortise and tenon (wedged or drawbored ideally, pegged as a third option).
- Bridle joint, which can be pegged if desired.
- Halving joint AKA half-lap joint (can also be pegged).
- End-grain to long grain butt joint, which can be reinforced with a through-dowel or screw*.

Note these *are* in approximate order of preference.

---

*Stainless steel or brass/bronze in preference, although it appears plain steel fixings are used in the frames in use with many paparmakers as odd as that seems.

Answer (score 0):

One more you could try: Cascamite. Very easy to use, it's a powder that you mix with water. Don't let that give the wrong impression though, once set it is completely insoluble/impervious to water. I seem to remember it has a pretty good shelf life too, as long as it doesn't get damp.

Comment: FYI Cascamite is a urea-formaldehyde adhesive.